# Webpack + React16 + Javascript ES6 "Unexpected token" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I know this question was asked about thousand times, but I didn't find any solution that works. I'm still getting the same error. Here are my config files:

package.json:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server",
        "build": "webpack"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "react": "^16.1.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.1.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel": "^6.23.0",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
        "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
        "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/app.jsx',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            }
        ],
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query:
                    {
                        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                    }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/app/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    }
};
```

app.jsx:

```
import React from "react"

React.render(<h1>hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root-component"));
```

Webpack throws the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import React from "react"
|
| React.render(<h1>hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root-component"));
```

I tried multiple solutions (like adding .babelrc file with presets), nothing works. Any help?

Comment: have you tried `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` instead of using `React` to render the app in the browser?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Same result.

Comment: According to the React documentation you have to use `ReactDOM.render`. Of course, as @AranS already suggested, you have to use `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` as well (note that ReactDOM is just a name).

Comment: Do you have `.babelrc` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webpack.config.js is incorrect as per webpack v3.

You need to add another entry into the `rules` array just like you are doing for loading CSS.
Moreover `query` should be renamed `options`.

See [Webpack Documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules) for more info on migrating from v2 to v3

The fixed `webpack.config.js` is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app/app.jsx',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
        hot: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/app/index.html'
        }),
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js'
    }
};
```

Before:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.jsx
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:13)

Ater (bundle correctly created):

`app.bundle.js        424 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
    app.bundle.js.map    499 kB       0  [emitted]         main`